# Open PDF or Folder

Tags: file, pdf, flash, actionscript

I try to open PDFs or folders (in finder/explorer) triggered by a mouse click in a swf application running in flash player.

Opening a PDF via urlRequest and `navigateToUrl()` always opens the browser.

I read about [this](http://www.artfans.info/open-pdf-file-from-flash-using-fscommand/) solution with fscommand and it seems that we have to write shell scripts for mac and PC. Doesn't sound perfect.

The swf is executed on cd ROM. So I think we can't use an air application and the classes of the air framework (File... etc.).

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we go now with zinc. it seems to be very powerful. you can create a exe from any swf. zinc let´s you implement many functions in actionscript, that give you access to the system. open pdf or something it the smallest task then :) cheers, florian

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you unfortunately **cannot** open a *PDF* into *flash* natively. It sounds like these *PDF*s are *static assets* on your *CD ROM* so I would take a look at a *PDF* -> *SWF* conversion tool. Maybe something like [swftools](http://www.swftools.org/). All of this in efforts to replace your current *PDF*s with *SWF*s which you can then load via the `flash.display.Loader` class.

Comment: hey thanks! we go now with zinc. it seems to be very powerful. you can create a exe from any swf. zinc let´s you implement many functions in actionscript, that give you access to the system. open pdf or something it the smallest task then :) cheers, florian

Comment: Sounds pretty sweet. Post that as your answer and accept it and hopefully someone else will benefit from your good find as well!