# Is that possible to play pdf files in flash player VB?

Tags: pdf, vb6, flash, pdf-conversion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Open PDF or Folder in Flash Player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6950774/open-pdf-or-folder-in-flash-player)

In my VB windows application, user will upload the pdf files and i have to show it in a flash player.So, i want to convert the pdf into exe file,then i can easily play with flash player by using **openwith** dialog box by invoking following **shell** command.

```
Shell("rundll32.exe shell32.dll, OpenAs_RunDLL " & exePath);
```

But i dont know it is possible to convert pdf file into exe file through VB.If not please suggest me a good approach for play the pdf in flash player...

Or Is there any way to play the pdf files into flash player?

Comment: Oh my god. Calling `rundll` via `Shell` is backwards. It’s like sending a text file from your application to notepad.exe and sending keys to the application to save it. First off, you can just call the WinAPI function in your code directly. But more importantly, you don’t need to, since you can just use the .NET framework: `Process.Start`.

Comment: Anyway, why do you want to use the flash player instead of the default PDF displayer? It’s highly recommended to use the user’s default application for a file instead of going through hoops to launch some other application.

Comment: VB6 or VB.Net? Your code sample is invalid in both. Please retag and update the question to suit.